# mostrar datos DataTable c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, poo

quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal en mi código; deseo obtener los datos de una tabla de mi BD; en la tabla tengo 2 registros .. pero el método sólo está que me devuelve un resultado. Este es el método que tengo en mi Capa_Persistencia:

```
public DataTable ListarUsuarios()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand comando = conexion.obtenerComandoSP("SP_ObtenerUsuarios");
            SqlDataReader resultado = comando.ExecuteReader();
            if (resultado.Read())
            {
                dataTable.Load(resultado);
            }
            resultado.Close();
            return dataTable;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Prueba a quitar la sentencia if y deja sólo el dataTable.Load(resultado);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El resultado que obtienes en un [SqlDataReader](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) es "forward-only", esto significa que una vez que lees un registro, no lo puedes volver a leer.
En tu método, la instrucción `if (resultado.Read())` lee y descarta el primer registro y por esa razón no aparece en el DataTable.
Para validar si la consulta devuelve resultados, debes cambiar la instrucción `if (resultado.Read())` por `if( resultado.HasRows )`. La propiedad `HasRows` devuelve `true` cuando el SqlDataReader contiene uno o más registros.

Con este cambio, el método quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public DataTable ListarUsuarios()
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        SqlCommand comando = conexion.obtenerComandoSP("SP_ObtenerUsuarios");
        SqlDataReader resultado = comando.ExecuteReader();
        if (resultado.HasRows)
        {
            dataTable.Load(resultado);
        }
        resultado.Close();
        return dataTable;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Otras recomendaciones relacionadas con el método pero no con la pregunta:

- En el bloque catch: si el objetivo es reenviar la excepcion tal como se recibe, entonces utiliza solamente `throw;`. La forma como lo utilizaste, reemplaza el 'stack trace' de la excepción original. [ver mas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw#re-throwing-an-exception)
- Agrega un bloque `finally` para liberar (Dispose) los recursos utilizados. [ver más](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch-finally)

  ```
  //Ejemplo:
  catch {...}  
  finally
  {
      resultado?.Dispose();
  }
  ```
- Es recomendable abrir y cerrar la conexión a la base de datos cada vez que se necesite.

Comment: Gracias! me solucionó el problema! :D